# Is SharePoint 2010 enough stable for production use

Tags: sharepoint-2010

This question may sound kinda weird but actually, I need to convince my mangement of the stability of the newest SharePoint 2010 Platform.

What I would like to know is:

- Is there anyone using SharePoint 2010 in a production environment
- Which kind of use of SharePoint environment (documents database, intranet, ...)
- How many users
- Your degree of hapiness (user experiences, bugs, problems with the environment)

Your answer will help me to convince my management to switch to MOSS 2010 instead of 2007.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have lots of working SharePoint 2010 environments at customers! Live and working in production environment. And I have yet to meet a customer that is unsatisfied with the "newer" version. We have ported 2007 -> 2010. And its mostly Intranets on our part...

We have between 30-150 users.

The easiest way for us to convince the customer is to show some Reference cases. And together with some good sales people ofc! ;)

Answer (score 0):

yes definitely sharepoint 2010 is stable enough for Production environment.